# XXX on output ports

Tags: verilog, hdl, xilinx-ise

I have written an asynchronous FIFO buffer, but when I run it, I get XXX on output ports. I referred to questions on SO which said asserting reset signals should make it work, but despite of doing it, I am still facing the same issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
module fifo 
    #(parameter width =8,
                           addr_width = 4,
                            depth = (1 << addr_width)
     )
     ( // Read port
      output  [width - 1:0] dout,
      output reg                 empty_out,
      input wire                 rd_en,
      input wire              rclk,
      //write port
        input wire [width-1:0]  din,
        output reg                  full,
        input wire                  wr_en,
        input wire                  wclk,
        
        input wire                  rst
);

(* ram_style = "bram" *)
reg [width-1:0] memory_s[depth-1:0];
reg [31:0] push_ptr;
reg [31:0] pop_ptr;

assign dout = memory_s[pop_ptr];  // assign cannot assign values to registers
always @(posedge wclk)
    begin
        if (rst == 1)
            push_ptr <= 0;
        else if(wr_en == 1)
            begin
                memory_s\[push_ptr\] <= din;
                //$display("w: %d", push_ptr);
            if (push_ptr == (depth -1))
                    push_ptr <= 0;
            else 
                push_ptr <= push_ptr + 1;
        end
    end

always @ (posedge rclk)
    if (rst == 1)
        pop_ptr <= 0;
    else if (rd_en ==1)
        begin
                //dout <= memory_s\[pop_ptr\]; 
                //$display("r: %d", pop_ptr);
            if (pop_ptr == depth-1)
                pop_ptr <=0;
            else
                pop_ptr <= pop_ptr+1;
        end

reg full_s;
reg overflow;

always @*
begin
        if (rst == 1)
            full_s <= 0;
        else if (push_ptr <= pop_ptr)
            if (push_ptr + 1 == pop_ptr)
               begin
                full_s <= 1;
                $display("push,pop,full: %d %d %d", push_ptr,pop_ptr,full_s); 
                end
            else 
                full_s <=0;
        else 
            if(push_ptr + 1 == pop_ptr + depth) 
               begin
                full_s <= 1;
                $display("push,pop,full: %d %d %d", push_ptr,pop_ptr,full_s);
                end
            else
                full_s <= 0;
        
        end
endmodule]
```

Here is a waveform:

[image: waveform]
([external link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8k7d.png))

Added Testbench
module fifoTb;

```
// Inputs
reg rd_en;
reg rclk;
reg [7:0] din;
reg wr_en;
reg wclk;
reg rst;

// Outputs
wire[7:0] dout;
wire empty_out;
wire full;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
fifo uut (
    .dout(dout), 
    .empty_out(empty_out), 
    .rd_en(rd_en), 
    .rclk(rclk), 
    .din(din), 
    .full(full), 
    .wr_en(wr_en), 
    .wclk(wclk), 
    .rst(rst)
);
initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    rd_en = 0;
    rclk = 0;
    
    wr_en = 0;
    wclk = 0;
    rst = 1;
    din = 8'h0;
    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;
  rst = 0; 
    wr_en = 1;
    din = 8'h1;
    #101 din = 8'h2;
    rd_en = 1;
    // Add stimulus here

end

always begin #10 wclk = ~wclk; end

always begin #10 rclk = ~rclk; end
endmodule
```

Comment: You're code looks strange on a combinational block that includes a reset. Usually, reset is not included on a combinational block.

Comment: Since, you did not inlclude a testbench in you post, I assume that `memory_s` don't have a value initialized. Thus `memory_s` outputs 'bx values. Try asserting `wr_en` first (write a value to `memory_s`) then assert `rd_en` (to read the value which was written in `memory_s`).

Comment: I tried asserting write and then enabling read but still for first 100 ns I get invalid output on my dout signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding additional logic on your output `dout` signal
to avoid having `'bxxx` values because `memory_s` has an initial value
of `'bxxx`:

```
assign dout = (rd_en) ? memory_s[pop_ptr] : 0;
```

*Additional* tips in creating your testbench:

First, it is very important to try to understand how your
device works.

Upon reading your RTL code, I concluded that your fifo works in the
following manner:

**Write operation**

```
always @(posedge wclk)
  begin
     if (rst == 1)
       push_ptr <= 0;
     else if(wr_en == 1)
       begin
          memory_s[push_ptr] <= din;
          if (push_ptr == (depth -1))
            push_ptr <= 0;
          else
            push_ptr <= push_ptr + 1;
       end
  end
```

When `wr_en` is high, two operations are performed.

1. The value from `din` will be written on `memory_s` pointed by
   `push_ptr` at the next positive edge of `wclk`.
2. If `push_ptr` is equal with `(depth -1)`, `0` will be written to
   the register `push_ptr` else register `push_ptr` is incremented by 1
   instead.

   Write operation will not be performed when `wr_en` is low.

**Read operation**

```
assign dout = memory_s[pop_ptr];

always @ (posedge rclk)
  if (rst == 1)
    pop_ptr <= 0;
  else if (rd_en ==1)
    begin
       if (pop_ptr == depth-1)
         pop_ptr <=0;
       else
         pop_ptr <= pop_ptr+1;
    end
```

When `rd_en` is high, increment the register `pop_ptr` by `1` if
  `pop_ptr` is not equal to `depth-1` else write it with `0` instead.
  `dout` will all the time hold the value of `memory_s` pointed by the register
   `pop_ptr`.

Creating tasks for every operation that you are going to perform
is usually convenient.

```
  wr_en = 1;
  din = 8'h1;
  #101 din = 8'h2;
  rd_en = 1;
```

I created write and read tasks for you as an example and you might want
to substitute your code above.

```
task write(input [7:0] pdin);
   $display("[ testbench ] writing data: %0x", pdin);
   din <= pdin;
   wr_en <= 1;
   @(posedge wclk);
   din <= 0;
   wr_en <= 0;
endtask

task read(output [7:0] prdata);
   rd_en <= 1;
   @(posedge rclk);
   prdata = dout;
   rd_en <= 0;
   $display("[ testbench ] reading data: %0x", prdata);
endtask
```

Here is how to use the tasks:

```
  write(8'hAA);
  read(read_data);

  write(8'hCC);
  read(read_data);

  write(8'hBC);
  read(read_data);
```

In writing a combinational circuit, it is not recommended to add
a reset logic on to it.

```
 always @*
 begin
         if (rst == 1)
             full_s <= 0; . . .
```

Also, most of the EDA tool vendors recommend to use blocking (`=`) assignment
in writing a combinational circuit and non-blocking assignment (`<=`) in a
sequential circuit.

End you're simulation when you're done by calling `$finish`.

```
initial begin
   #1000; $finish;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions. I have two question here: in each of the read and write tasks what are we we achieving with this:  **@(posedge wclk)  din <= 0;   wr_en <= 0;** Also in read why do we need blocking assignment **prdata = dout;**